# Need to access encrypted pass phrase

Tags: ecryptfs

My system is telling me that to restore test so I can retrieve files in the case of an emergency i need my encrypted password. I have tried the command `ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase`  and I get:

```
ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase [file]
```

or

```
printf "%s" "wrapping passphrase" | ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase [file] -
```

Neither works. Can someone help me please as i am a Newby to UBUNTU.

Bob

Comment: Hmmm. You should have chosen your encryption passphrase when setting up encryption. There is NO way to get the system to reveal the passphrase later - that would be a huge security hole! The entire point of encryption is to deny access to everybody who does not already know the passphrase.

Comment: Do you still have your user / login passphrase? You can use that with `ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase` to "unwrap" and reveal ecryptfs's actual mount passphrase. It's a good idea to save the mount passphrase somewhere as a backup, but everything *should* work ok without it anyway, as long as your login passphrase doesn't get lost or changed "the wrong way" (by another root user without you)